# Can a Sencha Touch 2 Ext.List component have subcomponents instead of using HTML in the itemTpl property?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'd like have a list with interactive components within each list item, such as multiple buttons and labels that I can toggle the hidden status of.  Is this possible?

We basically want to have an accordion-type list that allows you to expand each list item and expose a detailed view of the item.  The expanded view may have multiple actions, each requiring a different button.

As a work around, we just have a panel with a vbox layout.  This basically works, but it seems like we lose a lot of the benefits of having a list.  Is this the only possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have previously encountered this as well, I replaced my list with a [dataview with items](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-cfg-items)

Comment: I just tried a proof of concept with this component, but it doesn't repeat the sub-components that you specify in the items list and it doesn't appear that you can bind values in any kind of template.

Comment: Actually, it appears that List just extends the DataView component, so DataView is just a subset of the List component, so it most likely does not do what I need.  Did you get the dataview to do what you needed?  Can you post code?